# Layout bounds of a group and invisible elements in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a number of nodes in a group, whose visibility I would like to control using the `visibleProperty()`. I have observed that turning visibility of an element off affects the layout bounds of the group. They are recalculated as if the element wasn't there at all, not just wasn't visible. Is there a way to keep the presence of a node, but just turn off its visibility, so that the layout bounds were adjusted as if the node was there the whole time?

Example to ilustrate the problem, let's assume that the nodes are circles below.

```java
        Circle c1 = new Circle(0.0, 0.0, 3); // radius is 3
        Circle c2 = new Circle(10.0, 10.0, 3);
        Circle c3 = new Circle(20.0, 20.0, 3);

        Group g = new Group();

        g.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2, c3);
        Bounds b1 = g.getLayoutBounds();

        c3.visibleProperty().setValue(false);
        Bounds b2 = g.getLayoutBounds();
```

Above bounds `b and b2` will span:

```
b1 = BoundingBox [minX:-3.0, minY:-3.0, minZ:0.0, width:26.0, height:26.0, depth:0.0, maxX:23.0, maxY:23.0, maxZ:0.0]
b2 = BoundingBox [minX:-3.0, minY:-3.0, minZ:0.0, width:16.0, height:16.0, depth:0.0, maxX:13.0, maxY:13.0, maxZ:0.0]
```

Bounds `b2` are calculated after turning off the visibility of circle `c3`, so they shrinked with respect to the original bounds `b1`. I would like to have the method of having the bounds expanded to `b1`, even though some elements in the group are not visible.

**Edit**
Minimal reproducible example:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Circle c1 = new Circle(0.0, 0.0, 3); // radius is 3
        Circle c2 = new Circle(10.0, 10.0, 3);

        Circle c3 = new Circle(20.0, 20.0, 3); // radius is 3
        Circle c4 = new Circle(30.0, 30.0, 3);

        Group g1 = new Group();
        Group g2 = new Group();

        g1.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2);
        g2.getChildren().addAll(c3, c4);

        Group main = new Group(g1, g2);

        CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox("Show");
        g2.visibleProperty().bind(checkBox1.selectedProperty());

        Bounds b1 = main.getLayoutBounds();
        System.out.println(b1);

        checkBox1.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean t1) {
                System.out.println(main.getLayoutBounds());
            }
        });

        HBox hbox = new HBox(checkBox1, main);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 400, 300);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Stackoverflow, are you happy now?");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Now, any time you select the checkbox, not only 2 of 4 circles appear, but you will also see that layout bounds of the group change. The problem is that I need to know all the time the layout bounds as if all the groups were visible. I can't store the bounds value when they are all visible, because for simplicity I included here only 4 circles, while in real application, they are in thousands and they are moving around also when not visible, and there are also other objects of different sizes bound to them, which may expand the layout bounds of the main group even more.

Comment: Make sure [manged property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#managedProperty) is set to true.

Comment: @c0der: managed property is set to true by default

Comment: In my real application I am using Pane to display all the objects. It is a scrollable pane with introduced zoom mechanism, and I do not know what happens when I place another Pane on it. Also, there are different groups whose visibility is controlled, and element from different groups are mixed.

Comment: still wondering what you are trying to achieve: looks like an x-y-problem to me. What do you need the layoutBounds for? You did read and understand the api doc of the property, didn't you (and noted the difference of resizable/not resizable on computing them)? To see the difference, change the main Group to a Region and the layoutBounds don't change with visibility.

Comment: In my project I have a main Pane, containing the main Group of various elements. The elements move around the Group, may become invisible and may assume negative coordinates. As they move, the bounds of the Group, and the Pane expand or shrink automatically, I have also two side Panes ("Rulers") synchronized with main Pane that present position of objects. As the main Pane expands or shrinks, so must the ruler Panes. Therefore I need to know the layoutBounds of the main Group (in the range -inf:+inf, not 0:+inf) so to adjust the size of the rulers.

Comment: When I replaced Group with Pane, they are indeed not changing with visibility, but the height of the Pane expands to the height of the main window, even though I explicitely called ```main.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);```  Also it shifts everything to the positive range.

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution.

```java
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

public class ShapesGroup extends Group {

    public final BooleanProperty transparentProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    private final ObservableList<Shape> shapes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ShapesGroup() {
        Bindings.bindContent(getChildren(), shapes);

        shapes.addListener((ListChangeListener<Shape>) change -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    for (Shape shape : change.getAddedSubList()) {
                        shape.fillProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Paint>) (observable, oldFill, newFill) -> {
                            transparentProperty.addListener((ChangeListener<Boolean>) (observable1, oldTransparent, newTransparent) -> {
                                if (!newTransparent) {
                                    shape.setFill(oldFill);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        transparentProperty.addListener((ChangeListener<Boolean>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                            if (newValue) {
                                shape.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public ObservableList<Shape> getShapes() {
        return shapes;
    }
}
```

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(40, 40, Color.YELLOW);
        Circle circle = new Circle(20, Color.RED);
        ShapesGroup group = new ShapesGroup();
        group.getShapes().addAll(rectangle, circle);

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(group);

        Button button = new Button("Switch");
        VBox vBox = new VBox(stackPane, button);
        VBox.setVgrow(stackPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            group.transparentProperty.set(!group.transparentProperty.get());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, there are 2 problems with this solution. 1. I am controlling the visibility through a property bound to a checkBox and I can't control color using a property. 2. The circle is actually a small group of 2d shapes, so it has no single color.